# Android widget change margin on runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a android widget with a icon that shows a number in the right top corner in a little white circle. Now if my value is one character the value is right in the middle of the little whit circle. But when the value is 2 characters it is not right in the middle anymore.

What is try to do is if my value is more then 1 character then i want to change the left margin of the textview so the value is in the center of th white circle that is part of the icon.

I tried all ready with the

```
RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
updateViews.setInt(R.id.Value, "setMargins", 10);
```

But that gives a exception.
Is there a way of changing the left margin in a widget on runtime ???

My layout file looks like:

```
<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/widget_alarm" 
        android:id="@+id/imageAlarm"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/alarmCount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="58dip"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your textview in xml

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

Your text will always be in center.

Comment: I added the layout file. 
I use that has a margin-left of 58 dip. If my text is 2 characters or more i want to change my padding left to something like 56 dip or les so the text moves more to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :) It was indeed a quetion of adding a grafity:center to the text box.

I changed my layout to the following:

```
<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/widget_alarm" 
        android:id="@+id/imageAlarm"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/alarmCount"
        android:layout_width="25dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:text="000"
        android:textColor="#d21925"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageAlarm"
    />
```

Now the textview is aligned to the right of the icon and the width is the same size as the little round circle. The a grafity:center is working well.